# IPV6 implementation for all sites I am hosting

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

I am currently hosting provider. Ipv4 addresses are about to expire and it is becoming expensive to get slots. Can I implement IPV6 on all my network and also provide my clients only IPV6 address for the site I host? I am ready to put any gateway,dns dhcp whatever required for that.

Comment: I'm not quite sure where you're getting them from, but I certainly wouldn't call IPV4 addresses "Expensive". Our web-host provides a block of 4 addresses for $5/year. Or you can buy your own block for $3 per address (I think there's a minimum of 64 addresses) for however long you want them

Comment: I fall in APNIC region and my ISP charges $5 per IP per year. I think it's expensive. Can you tell me from where can I buy block of 64?

Comment: You can normally buy a block from your web-host. In Europe most (maybe all) address come from RIPE. Still $5/IP/year isn't that much (I'm assuming if you need more IP addresses, you're already running on a dedicated server so compared to the cost of that an extra $5/year isn't really that much). And remember, for every IPV6 address you'll almost certainly need a matching IPV4 address as quite a lot of ISPs still don't support IPV6, so your cost would actually be higher (Until there is universal IPV6 support)

Comment: @sam, unlike RIPE, APNIC has less than 10% of its IPv4 addresses left: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_address_exhaustion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run ipv6 if your upstream bandwidth provider allows you to, and if your network infrastructure supports it (more than just DHCP, etc., you need the relevant network switch / router hardware).

However, you won't get many customers offering just ipv6 hosting, since there are very, very few end users capable of viewing ipv6 only traffic (i.e. not your customers, but their users).  You would need to offer some kind of ipv4-to-ipv6 translation and build that into your solution.

From the basic nature of your question - I would surmise you're not ready to do this yet and should probably do a lot more reading first.

Comment: I am ready to put IPV6 routers and other stuff. I want situation like suppose one of my client hosts site and his domain name is example.com. Now can I assign only ipv6 to the example.com and yet make it accessible from all the users around the world? I am ready to make AAAA record for his example.com domain name so he does not need to depend on registrar .

Comment: Users all around the world don't have ipv6 to their home computers, so no, they won't be able to get to it.  You will need to provide ipv4 DNS entries, and do ipv4 to ipv6 translation at the edge of your ipv6 only network.

Comment: :-( providing dns entry for ipv4 and them map to ipv6 is bad business... I would like to buy some ipv4.. it  would be better. Anyway thanks for the answers.

Comment: I highly recommend you provision for *both*, right now. It's the best time to learn - i.e. before you Need It. http://www.he.net/ provides both free IPv6 connectivity via tunnel as well as training resources to help you learn more about IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

For the foreseeable future a lot of visitors to your site will not have IPv6 and will therefore still need to be able to reach it over IPv4. Because you are in the APNIC region and APNIC has already run out of IPv4 addresses you can expect that more and more of your visitors are going to get a bad IPv4 connection. ISPs will need to use NAT and other such mechanisms to supply their customers. Hopefully those ISPs will also offer IPv6 to those customers.

If you make your site reachable over both IPv4 and IPv6 those visitors won't need to go through NAT to reach you, which will probably give them a better experience.

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting doesn't provide native IPv6 you can use a tunneling provider like Hurricane Electric.

As an example the host company Linode has IPv6 native support at many sites but not all, tunneling can be used at those sites without.  They provide documentation to illustrate the task.

Tunneling guide:

http://library.linode.com/networking/ipv6-tunnels

Linode's native IPv6 guide for reference:

http://www.linode.com/IPv6/